# Print rows where all columns meet a certain criteria in a numpy array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an array with 500 rows and 5 columns. I need to find all the rows where the value in each of the last 4 columns is greater than 100. I found a way to check each column individually but I'd like to be able to check them all at once. I tried inserting an axis argument but it gives me an error. There must be a simpler way to do this. This is what I could get to work:

```
over1 = (array[:,1] >= 100)
over2 = (array[:,2] >= 100)
over3 = (array[:,3] >= 100)
over4 = (array[:,4] >= 100)
where = np.argwhere(over1&over2&over3&over4 == True)
there = array[where]
there2 = np.array(there[:,0]) 
#I had to reshape because the new array was a different shape for some reason
```

I'm new to Python and Numpy so I'm having some trouble

Comment: `array[(array >= 100).all(axis=1)]`

Comment: @Julien That worked. Can you explain how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for:

```
x[(x[:, 1:] > 100).all(axis=1)]
```

---

Consider `x`:

```
print(x)
array([[ 79, 192, 163,  94, 186],
       [111, 183, 152, 115, 171],
       [ 61, 125,  91, 163,  60],
       [110,  24,   0, 151, 180],
       [165, 111, 141,  19,  81]])
```

The operation `x[:, 1:] > 100` broadcasts the operation on every element, resulting in a boolean matrix.

```
print(x[:, 1:] > 100)
array([[ True,  True, False,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True, False,  True, False],
       [False, False,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True, False, False]], dtype=bool)
```

`np.all`, similar to the inbuilt function `all`, will evaluate to `True` if every element is `True`, else it evaluates to `False`. We want to perform this check every column per row, so we need `axis=1`.

```
mask = (x[:, 1:] > 100).all(1)
print(mask)
Out[362]: array([False,  True, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

The mask will now be used to index into the original.

```
x[mask]
array([[111, 183, 152, 115, 171]])
```